# What is the right format for a RSS file for Pinterest?

Tags: pinterest

I have tried to create a RSS feed that Pinterest can read ones every 24 hours and add pins to my boards. I looked at the docs that Pinterest have, but they don´'t even have an example file.

So I have created the RSS file and linked it to Pinterest and I get no errors when adding the link, but it is not working! It is not adding any pins to my boards so I guess I have something wrong in my RSS file.

I wonder, hwat should a Pinterest RSS file look like?

This is my RSS file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>My title</title>
<link>https://www.mywebpage.com/</link>
<description>Some text here.</description>
<item>
<title>The item title here</title>
<link>https://mywebpage.se/produkt/6740</link>
<description>The item description here</description>
<image>
<url>https://mywebpage.se/image.jpg</url>
</image>
<guid>https://mywebpage.se/produkt/6740</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I have tested a few different formats, but nothing is working.
So please, any input really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/auto-publish-pins-from-your-rss-feed) can help you. See the section `RSS feed specs` for the specification for the tags. Edit: Also, [try this RSS example](https://br.pinterest.com/feliciaday/geekin.rss)

Comment: Thanks Dante, but I have tried both of them. I have tried to create with this format as well<description><a href="https://www.pinterest.se/pin/1053912750269550572/"> <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/4b/98/26/4b9826d521327972bb986835463d956d.jpg"></a> </description> but then it can´t read the rss file.

Comment: Hm, maybe you need to pass some kind of Token in order for it to validate your requests?

Comment: No, you one add the link to the rss file and it should work, since I get no errors.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Hi IIýa, I have updated my question with what I got to work in the end. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have rolled back you edit. If you managed to solve your own problem, don't add things like "SOLVED" to the title, nor edit a solution into your question itself. Instead, post an **answer** and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried several times to get the correct RSS from support. Here it works for me. Be careful with the correct date format, this also affects validity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>My Site name</title>
    <link>http://example.com/rss</link>
    <managingEditor>support@example.com (myname)</managingEditor>
    <webMaster>support@example.com (name)</webMaster>
    <image>
    <url>http://example.com/android-chrome-512x512.png</url>
    <title>My site name</title>
    <link>http://example.com/rss</link>
    </image>
    <description>My site description.</description>
    <language>en</language>
    <pubDate>Wed, 29 Jun 22 03:47:23 +0000</pubDate>
    <item>
    <guid>https://example.com/img/739</guid>
    <title> Description image </title>
    <description/>
    <link>https://example.com/img/739/</link>
    <enclosure url="https://example.com/resources/964.jpg" length="83372" type="image/jpeg"/>
    <media:content url="https://example.com/resources/739_964.jpg" fileSize="83372" type="image/jpeg"/>
    <pubDate>Tue, 21 Jun 22 22:38:51 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```